# C# Do something while adding object to list

Tags: c#, list, user-controls

I have created a User Control called `Postbox` which contains a public List of User Controls.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DocEngineManager
{
    public partial class PostBox : UserControl
    {
        public PostBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<PostBoxPost> Posts = new List<PostBoxPost>();

    }
}
```

`PostBoxPosts` is the type of UserControl that the List contains.

When a user adds a `PostBoxPost` to the `Posts` List in their own application, I want to raise and event inside the class of my UserControl that knows what was added.

Comment: You should explain what you're trying to achieve in simpler terms.

Comment: A `List<PostBox>` in this way seems useless because `PostBox` is a control. A control should be added to `Controls` collection of its parent to be useful. *1)* What's your goal? *2)* Do you need only run-time support or you may need design-time support too?

Comment: I need design time and run time support. None of the answers below have helped yet so far. I need to know when a control is added and what control was added so I can edit it while it is being added or right after it is added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple List doesn't expose any events, something like [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) may work for you?

```
public partial class PostBox : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<PostBoxPost> Posts = new ObservableCollection<PostBoxPost>();

    public PostBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Posts.CollectionChanged += OnPostsCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnPostsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (PostBoxPost postBoxPost in e.NewItems)
            {
                // Do custom work here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ObserveableCollection` is kinda WPF leaning, a `BindingList` is the more Winforms version of doing it.

Comment: This method worked for me. I was able to find the added item on collection changed and make PostBox its parent by entering `Posts.Last().Parent = true;`.